# Filtering table with a subquery in the SELECT clause vs filtering with where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, join, subquery

So, I have the following two queries. In the first one, `rcv_transaction` table is first filtered by TRANSACTION_TYPE in the select clause, then joined to other tables while in the second query, the tables are first joined then filtered in the WHERE clause. Results are completely different. First query produces almost twice more results than the second query. For me, they should perform the same task. What am I missing here? What is the difference?

1st. Query

```
SELECT pl.*
  FROM po_headers_all ph,
       po_lines_all pl,
       (SELECT *
          FROM rcv_transactions r
         WHERE r.TRANSACTION_TYPE = 'DELIVER') rt
 WHERE     ph.PO_HEADER_ID = pl.PO_HEADER_ID
       AND rt.po_header_id(+) = pl.po_header_id
       AND rt.po_line_id(+) = pl.po_line_id
```

2nd query

```
SELECT pl.*
    FROM   po_headers_all ph, 
           po_lines_all pl, 
           rcv_transactions rt
     WHERE     ph.PO_HEADER_ID = pl.PO_HEADER_ID
           AND rt.po_header_id(+) = pl.po_header_id
           AND rt.po_line_id(+) = pl.po_line_id
           AND rt.transaction_type = 'DELIVER'
```

Comment: Not related, but: you should get used to explicit `JOIN`s instead of implicit joins in the where clause. Oracle also discourages the use of the proprietary `(+)` operator.

Comment: +1 for @a_horse_with_no_name I find explicit JOINs much more readable! And maintaining readability means actual cost reduction in the long time support and development...

Comment: Yeah, I know. It's just that all of the legacy code in the company I work for is written in that style. I have no authority to change the way they code :) Thanks for the advice though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using ANSI 92 join syntax your queries would be rewritten as:

```
SELECT  pl.*
FROM    po_headers_all ph, 
        INNER JOIN po_lines_all pl, 
            ON ph.PO_HEADER_ID = pl.PO_HEADER_ID
        LEFT JOIN rcv_transactions rt
            ON rt.po_header_id = pl.po_header_id
            AND rt.po_line_id = pl.po_line_id
            AND rt.transaction_type = 'DELIVER';
```

and

```
SELECT  pl.*
FROM    po_headers_all ph, 
        INNER JOIN po_lines_all pl, 
            ON ph.PO_HEADER_ID = pl.PO_HEADER_ID
        LEFT JOIN rcv_transactions rt
            ON rt.po_header_id = pl.po_header_id
            AND rt.po_line_id = pl.po_line_id
WHERE   rt.transaction_type = 'DELIVER';
```

Since your join to `rcv_transactions` is a left join when there is no corresponding row in this table the query will return NULL. 
However you your second query you are stipulating in the `WHERE` clause that `rt.transaction_type = 'DELIVER'`, therefore any rows where there is no match in `rcv_transactions` will be excluded because `NULL` does not equal to `DELIVER`. This effectively turns your LEFT JOIN into an INNER JOIN. In the first query though this predicate is part of the `JOIN` you are therefore not affecting the overall results, only the records that are joined.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer. So, as far as I understood, the only reason those queries are different is because an outer join is involved. What would happen if I changed all outer joins into inner joins? Would they still produce different results?

Comment: No, they would produce the same results.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the execution plan, you'll see that the 2nd query doesn't perform an outer join, as GarethD has already explained. Add the join operator to the last line to include it as a join condition:

```
AND rt.transaction_type(+) = 'DELIVER'
```